# How to add -f requirement to pip requirements.txt file

Tags: python, pip

I want to install Detectron2 looking at this tutorial
https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/install.html
but am not sure how to put the -f URL into a pip requirements.txt

everything I tried has given errors and I cannot find documentation on it.

[image]

suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to use requirements.txt? If you're trying to make a reproducible build, wouldn't conda env or Docker be more suitable?

Comment: @JanPokorný It is possible to reference another `requirements.txt` file using syntax `-r another_requirements.txt`

Comment: My bad, looks like both -r and -f are possible. I'd still recommend using conda or Docker though.

Comment: @JanPokorný, ...eh, if you're going to talk about reproducibility, I'd argue that Nix does it _far_ better than Docker. Too many Dockerfiles run `apt-get update` or `curl ... | sh -`, and then you have no reason to believe that two different runs of that same Dockerfile actually retrieved the same code/content off the network, and no way to tell after-the-fact if they did. With Nix, by contrast, you have a derivation that locks down _every_ input (addressed by the hash of those inputs!), and you can always ask after-the-fact what changed between builds, as w/ `nix-diff`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Nix looks like an interesting tool, thanks for the tip. My recommendation for Docker was primarily based on the fact that machine learning frameworks usually publish pre-built images with the heavy lifting already done. (This sadly does not seem to be the case here, Detectron2 published only the Dockerfile.)

Comment: @JanPokorný yes, that is sad, i am using docker and requirements.txt but also am going to be making it accessible via an API, fastapi or flask, so wanted to stick with pip. (poetry is nice too, but feels a bit odd with docker)

Answer (score 6):

requirements.txt

```
-f https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/wheels/cu111/torch1.8/index.html 
detectron2
```

pip isntall -r requirements.txt

Comment: Relevant documenation is here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format

Comment: for the hasty reader(me), fyi, `detectron2` has to be on the next line